# Validate Decimal number with Mathematic Operator using RegEx in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate string decimal number with some mathematic operator using `Regex` like

```
<=-5.6
<10
>=10
10.5
<=-20.4
2.
-.2
>-5.
```

**Invalid string** like

```
<>5
=>5.6
5.6>=
```

Comment: Any effort so far? Show what have you tried..

Comment: and where are you stuck at?

Comment: I tried but in some case its fail.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: Is this a decimal number .10.5?

Comment: In a situation like this I'm not sure RegEx is the proper tool for the task as your regex quickly can become quite complex. Might be easier for you to just do string manipulations against a dictionary of allowed operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex passes your test cases:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^([<>]=?)?-?(\d+\.?|\d*\.?\d+)$");
bool isMatch = regex.IsMatch(testString);
```

Comment: Looks good, but would also match `>=-` or `<=` but maybe that's allowed, who knows :) else could alter the digit part to somewhat like `(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+)$`

Comment: @Jonny5 Right you are, and I don't believe those should be allowed. I've updated my regex.

Comment: Thks u saved my lot of time.